# C++: friend as main in class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, friend

Can main function become friend function in C++ ?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A():i(10){}
private:
    int i;
    friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    cout<<obj.i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, now what's the question? Language syntax?

Comment: how does it work?   friend allows the function int main() to access the private variables and functions of class A.  A's constructer sets i to 10 int main() access i (as it is a "friend" and can access the private variable i) and couts it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can main function become friend function in C++ ?

Yes, it can.

The `friend` declaration in your class `A` grants function `main()` the right of accessing the name of its non-public data members (in this case, `i`):

```
friend int main();
```

The object `obj` is default-constructed, and `A`'s constructor sets the value of `i` to `10`:

```
A() : i(10) {}
//  ^^^^^^^
//  Initializes i to 10 during construction
```

Then, the value `obj.i` is inserted into the standard output:

```
cout << obj.i;
//      ^^^^^
//      Would result in a compiler error without the friend declaration
```

Answer (score 5):

3.6.1 of the Standard (wording from draft n3936, but it's the same in C++03) says that:

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program.

The exact meaning of this rule isn't clear.  The Standard formally defines semantics for the related term *odr-used*, but not simply *used*.

To be safe, assume that this rule means that "The function `main` shall not be named in a `friend` declaration."

---

Interestingly, although the wording of this rule is identical to C++03, in that version what we now know as *odr-used* hadn't yet been renamed, and this rule was clearly referring to that concept.  I wonder whether this was overlooked during the rename from *used* to *odr-used*.  If the new term was intentionally not used here, the rationale for that decision might illuminate what uses, exactly, are intended to be forbidden.

---

[Shafik found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320532/103167) that the rename took place in N3214, and this rule was intentionally not changed to *odr-use*, although it doesn't explain why.

Comment: A `friend` declaration does not odr-use the identifier though

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Right, but the Standard language forbids all use, not just odr-use.

Comment: OK, I thought you were speculating that it might be a defect and they meant to change it to *odr-used* along with everything else.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Ok.  Yes I am speculating that.  The rule used to mean *odr-used*, which went under the name *used*, and it no longer does.  Without clarification.  I would love to know whether this rule was discussed in the proposal that changed *used* to *odr-used*.