# Declaring main as friend considered harmful?

Tags: c++, c++11, program-entry-point, language-lawyer, friend

### Discussion

I know that `main` can be a friend of a `class`:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
  friend int main();
  int i = 4;
};

int main() {
  foo obj;
  std::cout << obj.i << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e8a021134b403f1)

However, I feel that although this is perfectably allowable it conceals many dangers.

### Questions

1. Are there any valuable uses in making `main` a friend of a class?
2. Are there any reasons that declaring `main` as friend of a class should be considered harmful?

Comment: This is really no different for `main` than for any other function.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making `main` a friend as such, is the reasons behind it that are usually the problem.

Comment: What "dangers" would those be, then?

Comment: The things we know, that aren't actually so...

Comment: I'm saddened that out of all of the horrible things I have done with C++ that this never occurred to me.

Comment: Opinion: Generally, "friend" should be a last resort if you really can't make it work reasonably any other way. Put a proper interface on foo() rather than friending it.

Comment: In my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25298934/1708801) I found a lot of details as to what *any use of main* means and the interpretation seems to mean *any* use period. I am debating whether to add an answer but will definitely do so if you strongly feel the new details I found are worth adding.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, go ahead. IMHO the 2 questions are quite related as to the contradiction they exhibit in contrast to the standard (i.e., "The function `main` shall not be used within a program"). Consequently, any arguments that support the claim `main` shall not be used anywhere else in the program are welcome.

Comment: Howcome this has +8, but [almost exactly the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048904/c-friend-as-main-in-class/) got -3 ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Are you asking me? I didn't down-vote. Seems like a question for meta though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The choice whether to use or avoid a legal feature becomes moot if the feature is not, in fact, legal.  I believe there's serious doubt surrounding this, because the Standard says

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program.

There's already a question regarding whether befriending `::main()` is in fact allowed, and you'll find more details in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071359/103167).

Comment: Cute question; best answer. Although this does appear to be an indisputable ambiguity in the standard.

Comment: So if I figured out correctly main shouldn't be declared friend at all, or at least avoid to do so?

Comment: Plus I think that that answer fits best to this question ;)

Comment: @40two: I definitely wouldn't do it.  But then, most often a `main()` function does little besides opening a log file, maybe install an exception handler, and then call an application-specific startup function.  Since that startup function is quite ordinary, it can be a friend.

Answer (score 8):

The general frienship considerations should be identical as for any other functions.

---

However I see one possible danger:

C++ Standard :

- **Section § 11.3 (Friends)**

> A function first declared in a friend declaration has external linkage

- **Section § 3.6.1 (Main Function)**

> The linkage of main is implementation-defined

So if your implementation expects `main()` not to have external linkage **and** you first declare `main()` as a friend (as in your example), you contradict the standard.

Comment: If you're using `std::cout`, you're probably not using a freestanding environment.

Comment: More to the point, it doesn't matter one whit whether your program is *required* to define a `main` function, it only matters whether your program *does* provide one, and surely whoever is writing `friend int main();` is fully in control of that.

Comment: @BenVoigt : I agree, I'll remove that note.

Answer (score 4):

Ben already indicated that the draft C++ standard in section `3.6.1` *Main function* says:

> The function main shall not be used within a program. [...]

but the term *used* is not defined and so it is not clear what the interpretation should be. Fortunately for us, we can find two pieces of evidence outside of SO that strongly indicates any *use* at all of `main` is ill-formed.

First we have this discussion in the [undefined behaviour study group discussion list](http://www.open-std.org/mailman/listinfo/ub) in the thread [What does "The function main shall not be used within a program" mean?](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2014-January/000474.html), this quote from [here](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2014-January/000488.html) seems to sum up the sentiment:

> C++98's mention of 'use' had a cross-reference to 3.2 [basic.def.odr].
>   C++11 no longer has the cross-reference, and was *not* changed to say
>   'odr-use', so I expect it means *any* use.

we have further evidence from [original proposal: N3154](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3154.html) to fix [Defect report 1109](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1109) would have changed `3.6.1` to:

> The function main shall not be odr-used (3.2) within a program. ...

but was amended when [accepted](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#US19) and we can see that the new [proposal: N3214](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3214.htm) changed to what we have today:

> The function main shall not be used within a program