# Why does gcc warn about decltype(main()) but not clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

Take the following code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    decltype(main()) x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

gcc complains:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:19: warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main' [-Wpedantic]
     decltype(main()) x = 0;
                   ^
main.cpp:8:19: warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main' [-Wpedantic]
```

but not clang. So what about `decltype(main())` raises this error? How does `decltype` take the address of main?

Comment: @Kerrek Yes but it only complains about `main()`.

Comment: Actually I was wrong; in a function call expression there is *no* function-to-pointer conversion if the expression is an lvalue (cf. 5.2.2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GCC's diagnostic might not be correctly phrased in this case, because `decltype` doesn't need to know the address of `main`; it only needs to know its type. However, the warning is based on the following from the standard (§3.6.1/3):

> The function `main` shall not be used within a program.

I suppose GCC interprets this to mean that you can't even use it in an unevaluated expression.

Clang (version 3.4 anyway) appears to not implement this rule at all, even if I turn on all the flags I can think of and even if `main` calls itself recursively. That's why it doesn't give you a warning.

Comment: This is a clang bug, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in clang, the compiler is not required to diagnose every silly thing users do, and by my reading a program that calls `main` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanWakely By my reading it's ill-formed. Isn't that what "shall" means elsewhere in the standard?

Comment: Shall just means that not doing that is undefined, it doesn't require a diagnostic unless it's also a constraint. However I think as a quality of implementation issue, clang should be warning about it since its easy to detect and not portable.

Comment: @Brian, in this case "shall" is a requirement on the program (i.e. the user) not the implementation (i.e. the compiler), although arguably [intro.compliance]/2 requires the implementation to issue a diagnostic if it's diagnosable, and using `main` should be diagnosable

Comment: You could also argue that for all platforms Clang targets, it's well-defined behaviour, so there's no need for Clang to issue a diagnostic. I believe that LLVM does not have any special stuff w.r.t. `main` so it would be impossible for Clang to target any platform where that stuff is forbidden.

Comment: There's no bug in Clang here; Clang rejects this if you use `-pedantic-errors` (at least in 3.5, I can't remember if I fixed this before or after 3.4 branched).

Answer (score 11):

This topic actually came up recently in the [undefined behaviour study group discussion list](http://www.open-std.org/mailman/listinfo/ub) in the thread [What does "The function main shall not be used within a program" mean?](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2014-January/000474.html). It does not come up right away but [here](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2014-January/000480.html) is where it starts in the thread with the following statement:

> I don't think decltype(main()) is an odr-use, or
>   sizeof(decltype(main)).

a very abbreviated set of responses looks like this:

> True, I just don’t see what utility those would be. You might mean
>   sizeof(decltype(&main)) in the latter case.
>
> I think the most common non-ODR use of main would be defining it after
>   a forward declaration, and now Steven Clamage has clarified that
>   should be ill-formed. The broader definition of “use” as being a
>   result of name lookup without reference to ODR looks correct now.

and:

> C++98's mention of 'use' had a cross-reference to 3.2 [basic.def.odr].
>   C++11 no longer has the cross-reference, and was *not* changed to say
>   'odr-use', so I expect it means *any* use.

and so it would seem that the interpretation of section `3.6.1` *Main function* which says:

> The function main shall not be used within a program. [...]

means *any* use even in unevaluated contexts and so `gcc` is correct here to produce an error although the message itself does not seem to make sense.

**Update**

It is interesting and instructive to note that the [original proposal: N3154](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3154.html) to fix [Defect report 1109](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1109) would have changed `3.6.1` to:

> The function main shall not be odr-used (3.2) within a program. ...

which would have allowed the `decltype` example but was amended when [accepted](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#US19) and we can see that the new [proposal: N3214](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3214.htm) changed to what we have today:

> The function main shall not be used  within a program

which would strongly indicate the opinion in the UB mailing list that *any* use of `main` is ill-formed is indeed correct.

Comment: See [CWG GitHub Issue 422](https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/422). This might resolve the ambiguity of what constitutes use of `main`.